# Auto Liquidity(Auto-LP) Bep20 contact

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix

I needed an automatic liquidity system for the rise and future of the token, how can I do this?
(I used ready-made code since I'm new to solidity)

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "My Token";
    string public symbol = "TKN";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;   
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly never use code, which you do not understand. There are way too many scams out there.

I would advise you to find a Solidity developer and let him write the contract. Even if the contract you find or design works, there is a high chance it will have vulnerabilities, which attackers will take advantage of.

Saying this, the code you posted is a Token, not a liquidity protocol. If you need a token I would advise you to look into ERC20 and use Uniswap's liquidity provision.